# Component of sum of two vectors in direction of the difference of two vectors.

Tags: vectors

Vector $\vec A $ and $\vec B$ are mutually perpendicular. What is component of  $\vec A $ +  $\vec B $ in direction of $\vec A $ -  $\vec B $   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component of a vector $\vec V$ in the direction of vector $\vec W$ is given by $\vec V\cdot \frac{\vec W}{|\vec W|}$.  Letting $\vec V=\vec A+\vec B$ and $\vec W=\vec A-\vec B$ reveals

$$(\vec A+\vec B)\,\cdot \,\frac{(\vec A-\vec B)}{|(\vec A-\vec B)|}=\frac{|\vec A|^2-|\vec B|^2|}{|\vec A-\vec B|}=\frac{|\vec A|^2-|\vec B|^2|}{\sqrt{|\vec A|^2+|\vec B|^2}}$$

where we used $\vec A\cdot \vec B=0$ to arrive at the final result.

Comment: You might want to check your work. Also, why must you give complete solutions to *everyone*'s homework? You have more than enough rep.

Comment: How does $|A-B|$ become $|A-B|^2$?